# Nginx serving to 2 ghost blogs in node.js

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, node.js, amazon-linux, ghost-blog

I'm trying to configure an Amazon EC2 instance running Amazon linux with nginx to serve two different ghost blogs in node.js.

My understanding is that web traffic hits the public IP of the ec2 instance, nginx is listening on port 80 and the config files for nginx reverse proxy each domain to the ports that the index.js file for each blog is listening for.

I'm using forever to run the two index.js files in the production environment but when I start both up, both domains (domain1.com & domain2.com) show the same content. It seems like starting the second index.js overwrites/redirects the traffic to the single ghost blog.

Maybe some of the configs might help:

## Home folder

```
ls ~
domain2.com  node  domain1.com
```

## Config.js for domain1.com

```
cat ~/domain1.com/config.js
 production: {
        url: 'http://www.domain1.com/',
        mail: {},
        database: {
            client: 'sqlite3',
            connection: {
                filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost.db')
            },
            debug: false
        },

        server: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: '2368'
        }
    },
```

## Config.js for domain2.com

```
cat ~/domain2.com/config.js
 production: {
        url: 'http://domain2.com/',
        mail: {},
        database: {
            client: 'sqlite3',
            connection: {
                filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost.db')
            },
            debug: false
        },

        server: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: '2369'
        }
    }
```

## Main nginx config

```
cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  domain1.com *.domain1.com;
        root         /var/www/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
        }
```

## nginx conf.d folder

```
ls /etc/nginx/conf.d/
domain2.com.conf  virtual.conf
```

## nginx domain2.com config

```
cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/domain2.com.conf
server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  domain2.com *.domain2.com;
        root         /var/www/html;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2369;
        }
}
```

## How I'm starting the ghost blogs

```
cd ~/domain2.com/
NODE_ENV=production forever start index.js

cd ~/domain1.com/
NODE_ENV=production forever start index.js
```

Sorry for the super long first post. Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: Does anyone need more information regarding this? I'm not sure if I put too much or too little.